# Exporting the SAS Project Log file

Tags: vbscript, sas, monitoring

I used to run 3 SAS EG Projects on a daily basis. Since a couple of days, we have a "SAS Scheduler" that is basically running those latter during the night (the first one at 00:00 AM, second one at 01:00 AM, third one at 03:00 AM). Each SAS Project has multiple SAS Programs.

All in all, that is great news, but this also mean I can't check the logs directly anymore.

To keep track of the night jobs, I am trying to find what could be the best way to export the log files for each project. I found out about the SAS Project Log recently, which basically summarize the logs from all the programs within a SAS Project.

I discovered [CaseySmith](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Auto-Purge-Project-Log-in-EG/m-p/436983/highlight/true#M28212)'s answer on the SAS Community forum, basically tweaking the `.vbs` script to save the SAS Project log file to a .txt using the following code:

```
Set objProjectLog = objProject.ProjectLog
objProjectLog.Clear()

objProjectLog.Enabled = True
'strProjectLog = objProjectLog.Text
objProjectLog.SaveAs "c:\temp\projectLog.txt"
```

But, 1) It is a .txt file not a log file and 2) I don't know where to add it in my current .vbs script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim app

Call dowork

'shut down the app
If not (app Is Nothing) Then
    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing
End If


Sub dowork()
    On Error Resume Next
    '----
    ' Start up Enterprise Guide using the project name
    '----
    Dim prjName
    Dim prjObject

    prjName = "C:\Users\kermit\Desktop\Project.egp"    'Project Name
      
    Set app = CreateObject("SASEGObjectModel.Application.8.1")
    If Checkerror("CreateObject") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '-----
    ' open the project
    '-----
    Set prjObject = app.Open(prjName,"")
    If Checkerror("app.Open") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
        
    '-----
    ' run the project
    '-----
    prjObject.run
    If Checkerror("Project.run") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
            
    '-----
    ' Save the new project
    '-----
    prjObject.Save
    If Checkerror("Project.Save") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '-----
    ' Close the project
    '-----
    prjObject.Close
    If Checkerror("Project.Close") = True Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
End Sub

Function Checkerror(fnName)
    Checkerror = False
    
    Dim strmsg
    Dim errNum
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        strmsg = "Error #" & Hex(Err.Number) & vbCrLf & "In Function " & fnName & vbCrLf & Err.Description
        'MsgBox strmsg  'Uncomment this line if you want to be notified via MessageBox of Errors in the script.
        Checkerror = True
    End If
         
End Function
```

In the end, what I would like is that on the morning, I run a program that scan the 3 project log files for Notes, Warning and Errors and send to myself an email with the results. Hence, is there a way to export the SAS Project Log (not manually) in a folder?

Comment: A text file with program output is a log file. You can give it the .log extension if you'd like to keep track of them a little easier.

Comment: I have no idea what the VBS code is doing but from the comments you probably want to put it between the RUN and the SAVE.  In addition to changing the filename extension from .txt to .log you might also want to include a timestamp in the filename so you can have more than one log for the same project.

Comment: @Tom The .vbs code is what is created when you schedule a job in SAS EG. What I want is to output the SAS Project Log File to an external folder in order to scan it for potential warnings/errors the next morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first, what is this code doing?

```
Set objProjectLog = objProject.ProjectLog
objProjectLog.Clear()
```

This clears the project log.  This needs to be done *before* your project is run - otherwise the log contains data from past runs.  So put this before the prjOBject.Run().

```
objProjectLog.Enabled = True
'strProjectLog = objProjectLog.Text
objProjectLog.SaveAs "c:\temp\projectLog.txt"
```

This then exports the project log to a text file.  You of course can call that text file whatever you want.  You need this code to appear *after* your program runs, and somewhere before it closes.  Right after PrjObject.Run() is probably fine.

You will need to update the names to match your vbs file's names - they use objproject and your vbs uses prjObject, but those are the same thing, just match the names.

Second - what else could you do?  If VBS isn't your thing, you have a lot of other ways you could do this.

- Export your EG project to a .sas file, then schedule this in base SAS with the normal output options.  This may also be possible via the scheduling interface.
- Use PROC PRINTTO to redirect your log inside your SAS code.
- Copy your EG project to a location you can see.  The EG project does contain the log of everything that was run - so there's no reason you couldn't just open the .egp and look at it, just make sure you're not doing that with the production file since you might forget to close out.

My preference is not to schedule EG projects, but to schedule .sas programs; use EG as the development environment and then export to .sas.  This gives you more flexibility.  But there are a lot of different ways to skin this cat.

Comment: I've been in an environment where we scheduled EG programs using the generated VBS code. The VBS code does work well and there certainly is something to be said about being able to visually see your process flow connected together and be able to identify the precise program that failed at a glance. But it did also have its drawbacks and was not as flexible as calling the sas executable. Adding things like SAS invocation options were more difficult, and very large process flows became cumbersome.